# Can I track nested object changes in React Context?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

**Repro:**

```
const defaultState = {
  value: 1;
  increment() {
    ++this.value;
  }
}

const AppContext = React.createContext({ myState: defaultState });
```

In the React component

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  static contextType = AppContext;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { myState } = this.context;
    myState.increment();
  }

  render() {
    const { myState } = this.context;
    return <p>{myState.value}</p>;
  }
}
```

**Expected**

Shows `2`.

**Actual**

Shows `1`.

How can I update React component when inner fields on my state changes?

Comment: As your variable perfectly describes `defaultState` is the default state which will be used only as fallback and will not be changed. To achieve your desired behaviour you will need to provide an actual updateable value for your context like described in [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component).

Answer (score 3):

The argument given to `createContext` is the default value of the context if there is no `Provider` component above the consumer in the tree. Mutating this default object will not cause a re-render of the consumers of the context.

You could instead put a `Provider` in a component which has `value` as state, and an `increment` method that updates the state, and pass these down through context with the `value` prop.

**Example**

```js
const AppContext = React.createContext();

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 1
  };

  increment = () => {
    this.setState(({ value }) => ({ value: value + 1 }));
  };

  render() {
    const { increment } = this;

    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={{ myState: { ...this.state, increment } }}>
        <MyComponent />
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static contextType = AppContext;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.context.myState.increment();
  }

  render() {
    const { myState } = this.context;
    return <p>{myState.value}</p>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. A cosmetic request: my context is quite big, `this.context.increment()` would be renamed to `this.context.myStateIncrement()`, same as `myStateDecrement` and `myStateValue`. There's no way to have them regrouped under a `context.myState.{value, decrement, increment}`, right?

Comment: @amaurymartiny You're welcome! I updated the answer with your request.

Comment: Thanks. A whole React component seems a bit overkill for me to store one value. But if that's how it should be done, so be it.

Comment: @amaurymartiny Yeah, rendering a `Provider` is the way to do it. You could just have one single `Provider` with all your context values instead of many different ones if you prefer.

Comment: Re your last comment: that's what I want, a single `Provider`, to be able to use `static contextType = AppContext` (cf my original question). There's one component (`App` in your case) that holds all the state and passes it into the Provider. If the state is big, then this one component manages a lot of unrelated logic. Do you have some ideas how to refactor so that these logics are separated (in separate components, separate modules...)?

Comment: @amaurymartiny If you want to split up all the context in your app into separate contexts and components, you would need multiple `Provider`s. If you can use hooks, it's a lot easier to consume context with the [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191304/discussion-between-amaurymartiny-and-tholle).